# Applying CSS to .NET ImageButton

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton, css

I have the following CSS that I can apply to an HTML input tag.

```
#headerSearch
{
    width: 265px;
}

#headerSearch .text
{
    width: 215px;
}

#headerSearch #searchButton
{
    background: url(../images/searchButton.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 36px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
}

#headerSearch #searchButton:hover
{
    background: url(../images/searchButton.png) no-repeat 0 -28px;
}
```

And the HTML to which I apply it...

```
<div id="headerSearch" class="float">
  <input id="txtSearch" class="text left" type="text" />
  <input id="searchButton" class="submit right" type="submit" value="" />
</div>
```

It works wonderfully.

However, I want to use an ImageButton control instead of the input tag because I want the page submit behavior of the ImageButton (which occurs when you click on it and click event is raised, etc.), but I am not sure how to go about mixing CSS with the ImageButton. I tried something simple like

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnSrch" runat="server" CssClass="searchBtn" onclick="ibtnSrch_Click" AlternateText="Search" />
```

but what occurs is the image displays with a red X in a white box (the default image is missing icon) over top of it.

**So, more succinctly, how do I mix elegant CSS with the .NET ImageButton?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short I would not use the asp image button.

I would use your current html controls and then add some javascript to click a hidden asp:Button control when your submit input is clicked.

```
<div id="headerSearch" class="float">
  <input id="txtSearch" class="text left" type="text" />
  <input id="searchButton" class="submit right" type="submit" value="" onclick="<% hiddenSearch.ClientID %>.click();" />
  <asp:Button ID="hiddenSearch" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

I don't quite recall if that is the correct syntax to get the client id...

Comment: @Biff - No can do and here's why. I have RequiredFieldValidators on the webpage, and when the input tag tries to submit the page then the RFV's are triggered and can cause the page submit to fail. Ultimately, this is what led me to wanting to use the .NET ImageButton because it has the CausesValidation attribute and can submit the page without causing the RFV's to trigger.

Comment: @Jagd - So set CausesValidation on the <asp:Button /> ?

Comment: Ahh, wait I see. Change it from a submit input type to a regular button.

Comment: And if that doesn't work just use a regular image and put the onclick on the div.

Comment: Anyways, what I'm trying to say is the asp controls are a pain to work with stylistically. Let me know if you are having any troubling implementing it my way. I'll try to help.

Comment: @Biff - Yeah, I get what you're saying. You got me thinking I could maybe use jQuery to do a redirect once the input tag is clicked. And I had to change the type to 'button' as well. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: It works now. Thanks for your help! I just changed the type to 'button' and I have a jQuery function hooked to input click, which uses top.location.href to redirect the page to my search page.

Answer (score 1):

based on the sample code you have set the `<asp:ImageButton />` CssClass to `"searchBtn"` but there is no CSS for `.searchBtn`

perhaps add this to your css

```
.searchBtn {
    background: url(../images/searchButton.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
}

.searchBtn:hover {
    background: url(../images/searchButton.png) no-repeat 0 -28px;
}
```

---

an `<asp:ImageButton />` renders down to `<input type="image" name="ibtnSrch" id="ibtnSrch" class="searchBtn" src="" alt="Search" style="border-width:0px;" />`

since the control is an image input with no image source that is why you get a red x

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `searchButton` style to be a class, then you can just use an `<asp:Button>`

```
<asp:Button ID="ibtnSrch" runat="server" 
            CssClass="submit right searchButton" OnClick="ibtnSrch_Click" />
```

You can then put that button in a separate [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) or set `CausesValidation="false"`.

If you want to keep it all client-side and do the redirect to the search page in JavaScript but also want to take advantage of the ASP.NET validation you've set up on your controls, you can use the [client-side ASP.NET validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0.aspx).